# node http-server и скрипты на node

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, express

Могу ли я использовать стандартный http-server npm, а для обработки данных писать свой node js скрипт. То-есть, например, происходит отправка post-запроса с клиента, сервер принимает ее и подключает скрипт который считает данные которые пришли. И если такое возможно, то как должен выглядеть примерно запрос с клиента (какой путь прописывать), и что должно быть прописано в скрипте (желательно используя express).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопроса, но похоже что его можно решить с помощью документации по [express](http://expressjs.com/ru/4x/api.html)

Comment: я имел ввиду, что можно ли обращаться к какому-нибудь скрипту на сервере  через стандартный http-server, и что-бы этот скрипт принимал информацию, или все-таки нужно для этого поднимать свой собственный сервер на ноде

Comment: так, тебе в любом случае нужно поднимать сервер, ты можешь это сделать через стандартный модуль http или через сторонний и более удобный express, [пример на http](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) и что значит "обращать к скрипту"